# Hibernate - Cascading type from annotations to hbm.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-mapping, hbm

I'm currently asked to convert our POJOs hibernate annotations to hbm.xml files,

But I came across two annotations that I can't "translate" and doesn't find a complete answer to my question,

What cascading type should I use to reflect the following:
1)

```
@Cascade({CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE })
```

2)

```
@Cascade({CascadeType.MERGE})
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

*.hbm.xml* files have 6 types of cascade annotations. You just need to choose what you really need.

#### `cascade="none"`

The default type. It tells Hibernate to ignore the associations.

#### `cascade="save-update"`

Tells Hibernate to navigate the association when the transaction is committed and when an object is passed to `save()` or `update()` and save newly instantiated transient instances and persist changes to detached instances.

#### `cascade="delete"`

Tells Hibernate to navigate the association and delete persistent instances when an object is passed to `delete()`.

#### `cascade="all"`

Tells Hibernate to cascade both `save-update` and `delete`, as well as calls to evict and lock.

#### `cascade="all-delete-orphan"`

The same as `cascade="all"` but, in addition, Hibernate deletes any persistent entity instance that has been removed (dereferenced) from the association (i.e.: from a collection).

#### `cascade="delete-orphan"`

Tells Hibernate to delete any persistent entity instance that has been removed (dereferenced) from the association (i.e.: from a collection).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but everything is in production and working now, we kept annotation since no proper answer could be foudn but for my personal "culture" if I follow your explanation, there is no possibilities to use CascadeType.MERGE with hbm.xml ?